Showing that a set has measure zero?
Consider the probability space $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ of sequences $x = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$ where each $a_i$ is either $0$ or $1.$ Take $\sigma$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all cylinder sets $$C(n,A) = \{\textbf{x}| x_n \in A, A \subset \{0,1\}\}$$
that is, those sequences whose $n^{th}$ term belongs to some subset $A$ of $\{0,1\}.$ Let $\mu$ be the measure so that, given a finite collection $A_1, \dots , A_n \subset \{0,1\},$ we have
$$\mu (\{\textbf{x} \,|\, x_i \in A_i, i = 1, \dots , n \}) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n}\frac{|A_i|}{2}$$
Consider the shift map $T: X \to X$ defined by $$T(a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots ) = (a_2, a_3, \dots )$$
Assuming that $T$ is measurable and preserves $\mu.$ We want to show that $T$ is ergodic.
$(a)$ Show that the set $X_{\infty} = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots )\,|\,\exists N s.t. \forall n \geq N, a_n = 1 \}$ has measure zero.
Hint: Write $X_{\infty}$ in terms of nested cylinder sets with arbitrary small measure.
My question is:
How can I write $X_{\infty}$ in terms of nested cylinder sets with arbitrary small measure?
Is this a valid way of writing it $$X_{\infty} = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$$ with $$B_N = \cap_{n = N}^{\infty} C(n, \{1\})$$? Should my sequence of $B_n$ be increasing or decreasing?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Is $\mu$ a measure on ${0, 1}^\mathbb{N}$ coming from the Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]$?

What are the $a_i?$ What is the measure $\mu?$ This seems like a lot of context is missing. You haven't even defined $X.$

Presumable there is some set of consistent measures on barrel sets of $X$ that are extended to some suitable $\sigma$ field.

My bad, I will edit my post so sorry about that.

@ThomasAndrews done editing

@Jakobian I edited my post, sorry about that.

@copper.hat exactly, I edited my post sorry about that.

Let us prove

The set $X_{\infty} = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots )\,|\,\exists N s.t. \forall n \geq N, a_n = 1 \}$ has measure zero.

Proof:
For each $N \in \Bbb N$, $N \geqslant 1$, let us define $X_N = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots )\,|\,\forall n \geq N, a_n = 1 \}$. It is immediate that
$$ X_\infty = \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty X_N$$
So, it is enough to prove that each $X_N$ has measure zero.
Given any $N, p \in \Bbb N$, let us define $C_{N,p} = \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots )\,|\, a_n = 1 \text{ for } n \in \{N, N+1, \dots, N+p \}\}$. Then, we have that
$$ X_N = \bigcap_{p=0}^\infty C_{N,p}$$
and, $ \mu ( C_{N,p})= \frac{1}{2^{p+1}}$. So $\mu(X_N)=0$.

$X_N$ is countable right?

why did you define the $C_{N,p}$ like this? Are they still cylinder sets?

I also edited my question, I am wondering if you have an answer to my last question?

@Hope  The family ${X_N}{N \geqslant 1}$s is countable. So $X\infty$ is the union of a countable  family of sets $X_N$.

So your sequence of $X_N$ is increasing or decreasing?

@Hope , I defined $C_{N,p}$ the way I did, to ensure that $ X_N = \bigcap_{p=0}^\infty C_{N,p}$ and that $\lim_{p \to \infty} \mu ( C_{N,p}) =0$.
Yes, the $C_{N,p}$ are cylinder sets.

@Hope , The sequence ${X_N}{N \geqslant 1}$ is increasing. But, each $X_N$ has measure zero, and to prove it, we used the sequence ${C{N,p}}_{p\in \Bbb N}$, which is a decreasing sequence of nested cylinders.

@Hope , Regarding the last question you added to your question: IF your $C(n,{1}) = {\textbf{x}| x_n \in {1}}$, then you can write $X_{\infty} = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$ with $B_N = \cap_{n = N}^{\infty} C(n, {1})$. Those $B_N$ coincides to the $X_N$ in my answer.
